# Data Load Error Using ADF V2 to Sql Server on Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-server

I'm facing below error while trying to data load from On-Prem Db2 system to Sql Server on Azure Vm using ADF V2

```
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.),Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=10054,Class=20,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=0,Errors=[{Class=20,Number=10054,State=0,Message=A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.),},],
```

This happens only when i'm trying to load very large source table to target Sql server. Because when i changed the target to Azure SQL PaaS table got loaded successfully.

I'm not sure how to fix this data load issue and where should i start to trouble shoot this error.

Sql Server Error Log details:

```
" Message A fatal error occurred while reading the input stream from the network. The session will be terminated (input error: 10054, output error: 0)."
```

Please help here.

Note: I can't switch to Azure Sql PaaS offering as its not supporting any distributed transaction yet.

Answer (score 0):

> where should i start to trouble shoot this error.

You start with the SQL Server Error Log.  This is either a network issue, or a severe server-side error.

The client error message:

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server.

and SQL Server's error message

> " Message A fatal error occurred while reading the input stream from the network. The session will be terminated (input error: 10054, output error: 0)."

both agree that the network connection between the client and server failed.  If your ADF Integration Runtime is running on-premises inquire about any firewalls or network security devices that might be terminating the connection.

Comment: @user1941025 - please edit your original question to include any additional detail, rather than posting details under an answer (and asking for more help).